# Unnamed, non-existing .swf

Tags: jquery, flash, plugins, sifr

I'm using [jQuery sIFR plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/sifr/) for text replacement, although it works perfectly but there's a link to an unnamed and non-existing ".swf" file. Is it issue related to the sIFR plugin I'm using? How do I fix it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need flash code to build font_name.swf which can be used by sifr.js to replace normal text into flash movie.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. Like I said, sifr is working perfectly, I'm just annoyed by the mysterious swf.

Comment: can you some cite that particular piece of code? It might be some sort of fallback swf.